# Как правильно организовать парсер php?

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Пишу парсер для одного сайта. На сайте есть авторизация, это сильно усложняет, т.к. я в php новичок

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function curl_get($url, $referer = 'http://www.google.com', $fields = []) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $dom = str_get_html($data);

    $token = $dom->find('#big_login input[name="authenticity_token"]');

    foreach($token as $tok) {
        $fields["authenticity_token"] = $tok->value;
    }


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}


$url_auth = 'https://********/users/sign_in';

$auth_data = [
   "user[email]" => "123123sad@mailnow2.com",
   "user[password]" => "pass",
   "user[remember_me]" => "on",
   "authenticity_token" => "",
   "utf8" => "✓"
];

$page = curl_get($url_auth, 'http://www.google.com', $auth_data);

echo $page;



?>
```

По идее после вывода должна выводиться страница, где я авторизован, но нет, выводиться просто страница с авторизацией.

На сайте есть такой токен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Который я паршу в итоге, я так понял его тоже нужно отправлять, при авторизации

Что я делаю не так и почему выбивает страницу авторизации?